# why can't i define a function of return type 'pointer to struct' outside of class?

Tags: c++, pointers

**This code gives error 'no declaration matches Node* List::getNewNode(int)'**

```
class List
{
private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* next;
    };

private:
    Node* getNewNode(int data);
};

Node* List::getNewNode(int data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

**But the same definition of this function works inside of the class**

```
class List
{
private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* next;
    } *head = NULL;

private:
    Node* getNewNode(int data)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return newNode;
    }
};
```

Is there any difference in defining the function inside the parenthesis of class declaration and
using scope resolution to define it outside of the class parenthesis or the return type is the problem ??
compiler: minGW x64

Comment: Outside the class declaration, you must refer to the type as `List::Node`.  See https://godbolt.org/z/cxebdb

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a resolution of `Node`(since it's a nested class),if you define the function outside of class defition:

```
List::Node* List::getNewNode(int data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Even if  `Node` was public it would still give error, List::Node* is needed whatever the excess modifiers is

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the strange elements in C++. The problem is that the parser doesn't (ain't allowed to) know that you are using a subclass of List. Instead it searches for a class Node in the global namespace and all used namespaces.

To fix this, you should prefix the type with list.

```
 List::Node* List::getNewNode(int data)
```

Nowadays, you can also use trailing return types to specify your function.

```
 auto List::getNewNode(int data) -> Node*
```

As the Node is now after the function, the parser already knows you are in the List scope and can find the correct class. Together with this simplification, some people argue this is a more consistent way of writing code as it's similar to how lambdas work.